# Uniform Acceleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

> *A steel ball is allowed to roll from rest down a 20.0 m long slop and over a 25 m long level surface. It takes 4.0 seconds to roll down the slope. Calculate the speed at the bottom of the slope.*

I found the average speed on the slope to be 50 m/s. But, I'm not sure what formula to use to find the speed at the bottom of the slope.

Answer (score 1):

You have the $y = 25$, and the $x = 20$, you can calculate the angle from those, you know the gravity acceleration, the vertical acceleration will be $$ a= g \cdot sin(\theta) $$

And your speed will be $$ v = a\cdot t $$

EDIT:Mistake

Comment: Is there any other method of solving the question. In class, we didn't learn finding the angle yet. Thanks.

Comment: I am sure you are familiar with trigonometric functions, like tangent